# Multiprocessing does not seem to print output as expected

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a simple multiprocessing task as shown below:

```
def main():
    def do_something():
        print('sleeping 1 second')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Done sleeping')


    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the output:

```
sleeping 1 second
Done sleeping
sleeping 1 second
Done sleeping

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But I was expecting to output:

```
sleeping 1 second
sleeping 1 second
Done sleeping
Done sleeping

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am using a windows machine using vscode. It seems that multiprocessing isn't doing its function entirely, do I have to enable multiprocessing support or is it something else?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You **call** the function with the appended () before even the subprocess is started. First, you must remove the parentheses for the "target" argument. Second, you can't use a nested function as target on Windows. Move it to module level.

Comment: @MichaelButscher You should post this as an answer; it would only take you a minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

A process is not a thread, it is doing a diferente task, the process blocks until done. Note that it is deferment from a thread pool too. Olso is good practice to wait until all thread are done with `.join()` an make sure that they exit correctly

```
import threading as th
import time

def do_something():
    print('sleeping 1 second')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done sleeping')

def main():
    th_1 = th.Thread(target=do_something)
    th_2 = th.Thread(target=do_something)

    th_1.start()
    th_2.start()

    th_1.join()
    th_2.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A process started as the poster did does **not** block!

Comment: Its easier to to learn with `threading` than `multiprocessing`, as op said, its a simple code